# How to disable keybinding in Tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

Using Tmux and Vim is a pain sometimes. One of the collisions for me is `Control-S`. I use it in Vim for opening buffers in split, but when using Tmux, well...

Tmux does something stupid with it, I can't figure out whats the purpose. But basically, when `C-s` is pressed in Tmux, screen freezes. And it unfreezes with `C-q`. I've no idea whats that good for, if anything.

```
unbind C-s
unbind C-q
```

I tried to unbind C-s in tmux.conf, but it didn't work. How can I unbind it?

Also I freed the binding from Terminal, in `.bashrc`

```
stty -ixon -ixoff
```

Comment: To make sure that tmux registered the stated bindings you should check the output of `tmux list-keys` within your tmux session.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, I would say that the `Ctrl-S` (suspend the output) "feature" doesn't belong to tmux. The `Ctrl+S and Ctrl+Q` is actually the XON/XOFF protocol. It lives with Unix/linux for long time.

You can disable it by:

```
stty -ixon
```

or

```
stty stop undef
```

you could check by `stty -a` before and after the change.  easier is, try the commands above, and press `Ctrl-S` to see if it worked.

good luck.

Comment: I only have this problem when using Tmux. I already disabled suspend output thing in .bashrc. Somehow tmux enables it again?

Comment: Actually, adding `stty stop undef` on top of -ixon fixed it.