# Tmux is blocking Ctrl-s in OSX ML

Tags: macos, vim, tmux, iterm2

Im using iTerm2 + Tmux + Vim.

Here are my dotfiles:
https://bitbucket.org/furion/dotfiles/src

The problem I'm having, is when Vim is opened within Tmux session, the `C-s` binding doesn't work.

When I run Vim just in regular iTerm2 session, `C-s` works fine. Since I use this keystroke a lot, its really frustrating.

Also, this issue is only present on OSX. On my Arch box, Tmux or without, everything works fine.

EDIT:
I already have control flow disabled:

```
bind -r '\C-s'
stty -ixon
stty stop undef
```

This issue is only on OSX. Also, its only under Tmux on OSX. Without Tmux no issue. On Arch Linux With or w/o Tmux, no issue.

Comment: you had asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991007/how-to-disable-keybinding-in-tmux the solution there doesn't help?

Comment: No, that was a different problem, which has been solved. I got it to work on Arch that time.

Comment: I checked your .vimrc, you want to do `:w` when `<c-s>` was pressed? but that line was commented out.

Comment: No, I use it in `Ctrl-P` Plugin, to open files in split buffers. I have very strong muscle memory with :w, so I might as well remove C-s there.

Comment: Same problem happens to me and I haven't found a fix. It is intermittent almost random. Quitting vim and starting it again fixes it for a while. I think it mush be something with vim getting confused with something that tmux is doing. Maybe a mouse thing? I don't know. Crap... vim just crashed on me. I got to go...

Answer (score 5):

It probably has to do with flow control: historically (and still today, in some terminals), Ctrl-S pauses the output, and Ctrl-Q resumes it.

iTerm2 ignores Ctrl-S, as it assumes that it has no use for flow control in the world where 300 and 2400 baud modems are not all that common.

I am not sure, but I think `stty -ixon` might help.

(I'm tentatively answering since it's been 5 hours, but I might be way off on the solution, even though I think the cause is correct).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the fix, But I don't know the reason why this happens

I make a TMUX command to reload the config file also run `stty -ixon`.

This has to be done manually even though it is set in the `.bashrc` or `.profile` since the problem manifests itself *after* initialization.

Here is the [relevant TMUX config line](https://github.com/sukima/tmuxrc/commit/081b1ee51934806dfc92df76b3ffa5f78fbe610f):

```
bind-key r run "tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf; stty -ixon"
```

Comment: I have been looking for a solution to this for ages!
To others trying out this, if you get an error while reloading, try appending `; true` after `ssty -ixon` to squelch that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when trying to fix the problem of `Ctrl-S` in bash in iTerm on macOS not activating `forward-search-history` (aka: `i-search`) in spite of having:

```sh
$ bind -p | grep 'forward-search-history'
"\C-s": forward-search-history
```

I found that it **DID NOT solve the problem** to put `stty -ixon` in .bashrc but putting in in `.bash_profile` does solve it. So, maybe that will help others that Google leads here.

```sh
$ grep stty ~/.bash_profile
stty -ixon
```